# ng-click with ng-repeat not working with direct expressions (not functions)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am having an ng-repeat block and with it i am writing an ng-click with a direct expression of setting a $scope variable to true.. but it doesn't work.. can someone plz help.. here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wcte2869wKcThwTJAi6j?p=preview)

**HTML**:

```
selected: {{selected}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="t in t.header" ng-click="selected = true;">{{t.a1}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = false;
  $scope.t = {
    header: [
      {
        a1:'a1'
      },
      {
        a1:'a1'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

for now i am having a workaround to have a function call on its click and set the variable that is required, but curious to know whats wrong with the other approach?

Comment: there should be something like a $parent.selected, only selected doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $parent because ng-repeat creates it's own scope

```
<li ng-repeat="t in t.header" ng-click="$parent.selected = true;">{{t.a1}}</li>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezLUBMw2FskZUmexBDuX?p=preview)

Comment: $parent did the trick, marking this as answer as it is close match to my prob.. other solutions provided works as well.. thanks everyone..

Answer (score 2):

It's working, but because of the ngRepeat, selected is binded to the new scope. You can instead put selected in an object, so it won't create a new selected property on the child scope:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in t.header" ng-click="selectedObj.selected = true;">{{t.a1}}

$scope.selectedObj = { selected: false };
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FdMwKFFCmtEaXRAys6q?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//$scope.selected = false;
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.selected = false;
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7Eq6njIn9xb7k1C9KQs?p=preview)

What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.

For better understanding:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

Just use $parent scope, like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in t.header" ng-click="$parent.selected = true;">
```

Every item in ng-repat has his own scope.